# Breeze .expand fetching null for navigation property

Tags: breeze, expand

```
   public class Denial
{
    [Key]
    public string DenialCd { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DenialDesc { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CaseDenial> CaseDenials { get; set; }
}


public class CaseDenial
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DenialCd { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DenialCd")]
    public Denial Denial { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CaseId")]
    public Case Case { get; set; }
}

      var query = EntityQuery.from('CaseDenials')
            .where("CaseId", "==", caseID)
            .expand("Denial")
            .orderBy("DenialCd").inlineCount();
```

CaseDenial table links to DenialCd column of Denial table. Above breeze query brings null for the navigation property "Denial" while fetching records from CaseDenials.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your EF model is not attributed 'correctly'.  I would confirm that you can perform a server side Entity Framework 'Include' operation.  This is what Breeze is doing under the covers when you call a client side 'expand'.

Comment: .Include does not work as well. The attributes are no different from the other entities on which .expand is working correctly.

Comment: I got the problem. Because the DenialCd is a string property, .expand was failing. When I changed its type to int, .expand works. But I want that column to be of type string.

Comment: Strings should be fine but both the pk and the fk must be of the same type.

Comment: Yes they are of same type.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you have 1 denial with MANY case denials, then you should query as follows:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Denials')
    .where("CaseDenial.CaseId", "==", caseID)
    .expand("CaseDenial")
    .orderBy("DenialCd").inlineCount();
```

This should work. What you can try as well is adding `[InverseProperty("CaseDenials")]`